# Shell script parser or editor

Tags: bash, shell, editor

Is there an editor for shell scripts? Or is there an online parser or something similar to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editor: VI ;-) Seriously, any simply text editor will do. You may want to choose one with some kind of decent syntax highlighting though (again, VI, emacs, etc.)

Parser: If you look for a way to validate your scripts without actually executing them, look into the [`-n / noexec`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html) option.

Answer (score 0):

Any text editor can help in editing shell scripts,  U usually use VIM or GEDIT to edit shell scripts. And in a usability perspective, I felt gedit more friendly.

-n / noexec option. can be used to validate shell scripts.

Also adding -v option to the shebang
ie: #!/bin/sh -v 
will help you debug the script easily.